# Nested Higher Order Functions

Tags: swift, higher-order-functions

I am struggling to set up a higher order function using map and filter to create an array which contains arrays. I have been doing it now the hard way using for each loop. 
There must be a better way. hopefully, someone can help.

I know about simple things like `datasource.map{$0.category}` but struggling to get further.

```
var categoryDatasource: [[Kreisel]] = [[Kreisel]]()

    // METHODS
    convenience init(datasource: [Kreisel]) {
        self.init()
        var categories = [String: [Kreisel]]()
        for kreisel in datasource {
            if var val = categories[kreisel.category] {
                val.append(kreisel)
                categories[kreisel.category] = val
            } else {
                categories[kreisel.category] = [kreisel]
            }
        }
        categories.forEach { (key, value) in
            categoryDatasource.append(value)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Dictionary` constructor [init(grouping:by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127163-init) to create a `dictionary` from an array by grouping based on the given property `category`. Then you can get the values of the `dictioary` as an `array` like this

```
categoryDatasource = Array(Dictionary(grouping: datasource) { $0.category }.values)
```